# Unity2D prefabから複製を作る

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

Unity 5.3
やりたいことは、「プレハブを複製し、表示させる。」

```cs
GameObject prefab = (GameObject)Resources.Load ("Prefabs/hoge");
```

でプレハブを取得するのはわかります。
ついで

```cs
Instantiate(prefab, tran.position,Transform.rotation);
```

をするとエラーがでます。引数の部分が問題かと思い次のようにしても同様です。

```cs
Instantiate(prefab, 0,0);
```

インスタンスを作る、というところからコピーしたものなのに動かないのは何故でしょう。

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Start : MonoBehaviour {
    // プレハブを取得
    GameObject prefab = (GameObject)Resources.Load ("Prefabs/hoge");
    //Instantiate(prefab, tran.position,Transform.rotation);
    Instantiate(prefab, 0,0);
}
```

```
Assets/Script/Start.cs(8,29): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `0' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Assets/Script/Start.cs(8,21): error CS1041: Identifier expected
```

Answer (score 0):

いろいろ端折りすぎている関係で答えにくいですが、以下を試してください。

> Instantiate(prefab, tran.position,Transform.rotation);

まず、引数二つの設定を何を意図しているかわかりません。

> tran.position

tranはどこから？

> Transform.rotation

こちらはなんとなく設定しているGameObjectから取得しているのはわかります。

ひとまず設定に意図は恐らくないのでは、と推測させていただきます。
そのことから、

> Instantiate(prefab);

こちらで試してください。
後ろ二つの引数はなしでも動作します。

> Instantiate(prefab, 0,0);

恐らく引数が正しくないからだと思いますが、
前後スクリプトがないのでひとまずこちらの意見は控えます。

それぞれお試しください。

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartGame : MonoBehaviour {
 // プレハブを取得
 GameObject prefab = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/hoge");
 Instantiate(prefab);
 }

シンプルなソースにしましたが、上記ソースでエラーが出ます
Assets/Script/StartGame.cs(7,21): error CS1041: Identifier expected
Instantiate(prefab);　のb) のところで赤線がでてます

Comment: 根本的にオブジェクト指向を理解できてないように見えます。
エラー理由はわかりますが、
まずクラスについてを理解するところからはじめてください。

Comment: @user12948 追加情報をコメントで記載しないでください。編集から質問文を編集し追記してください。